# Select query to fetch required data from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data like this as shown below:

```
Acc_Id || Row_No
1           1
2           1
2           2
2           3
3           1
3           2
3           3
3           4
```

and I need a query to get the results as shown below:

```
Acc_Id || Row_No
1           1
2           3
3           4
```

Please consider that I'm a beginner in SQL.

Comment: any logic behind your desired result?, you didn't explain at all

Comment: Can you explain the logic? I am not understanding the logic for output..

Comment: If you don't have gaps then `count(*)` will be equivalent to `max(Row_No)`. The real question is whether you want the count or the maximum.

Comment: Not sure why this question got three upvotes. OP did not explain the question properly and there is no attempts made to solve the problem. Also question looks fairly simple to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner then this is your first exposure to aggregation and grouping. You may want to look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) on `group by` now that this problem has motivated your interest in a solutions. Grouping operates by looking at rows with common column values, that you specify, and collapsing them into a single row which represents the group. In your case values in `Acc_Id` are the names for your groups.

The other answers are both correct in the the final two columns are going to be equivalent with your data.

```
select Acc_Id, count(*), max(Row_No)
from T
group by Acc_Id;
```

If you have gaps in the numbering then they won't be the same. You'll have to decide whether you're actually looking for a count of rows of a maximum of a value within a column. At this point you can also consider a number of other aggregate functions that will be useful to you in the future. (Note that the actual values here are pretty much meaningless in this context.)

```
select Acc_Id, min(Row_No), sum(Row_No), avg(Row_No)
from T
group by Acc_Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the Count of the row

```
SELECT Acc_Id, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Acc_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Acc_Id, MAX(Row_No)
from table
group by Acc_Id
```